# Reverse substrings between each pair of parenthesis

Tags: c#

Dears,

I have been trying to solve the problem to "Reverse substrings between each pair of parenthesis".
I am having difficulty in understanding the algorithm.

For instance, for the input: (skeeg(for)skeeg), my program outputs geeksrofgeeks.

The code:

```cs
string sentence = "(skeeg(for)skeeg)";
string[] word = sentence.Split('(', ')');
for(var i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    Console.Write( new string(word[i].Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Comment: Well this website already offer explanation of the proposed solution. But there is a miss understanding as the expected solution is `geeksforgeeks` as "for" is in 2 parentesis. and get reverted twice.

Comment: The problem is that you reverse "for" only one when you need to reverse it twice.  Instead of splitting on the parenthesis you need to find the matching closing parenthesis and reverse everything between them and then find parenthesis inside that substring and do the same.  That or you have to keep track of how deep you are to know if you should reverse or not.

Comment: I added the following code:   ```string sentence = "(skeeg(for)skeeg)";
        int index1 = sentence.IndexOf('(');
        Console.WriteLine(index1);
        int index2 = sentence.LastIndexOf(')');
        Console.WriteLine(index2);
        string output = sentence.Substring(index1+1,index2-1);
        Console.WriteLine(ReverseString(output)); ``` and the result is geeks)rof(geeks. I have been thinking of using a recursive function for this, instead of a stack.

Comment: @AntónioOliveira The problem with that approach is if you have "(ffuts)and(erom)".  You don't want to reverse from the first open paren to the last closed.  You want to reverse the  **matching** paren pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Above algorithm is a tokenizer.

The Split isolates *(tokenizes)* any part that is not one of the delimiters "(" or ")" and the reverse is performed on each part. So your parts will be: skeeg for skeeg. Reverse each term will yield geeks rof geeks.

When your algorithm would be recursive *(parse)*, the middle part would be done 2x and output geeks for geeks. Because the Split() regards every delimiter as equal, you get the above result. A parser would see the difference between "(" and ")"

Comment: I added the following code:  ```string sentence = "(skeeg(for)skeeg)";
        int index1 = sentence.IndexOf('(');
        Console.WriteLine(index1);
        int index2 = sentence.LastIndexOf(')');
        Console.WriteLine(index2);
        string output = sentence.Substring(index1+1,index2-1);
        Console.WriteLine(ReverseString(output)); ``` and the result is geeks)rof(geeks. I have been thinking of using a recursive function for this, instead of a stack.

Comment: Yes, your code is ok but it does not meet the requirements ! You better set up a recursive function instead.. you do the recurse when you find "(", you do the return when you find ")" .. and then .. you will find that the middle term is reverted 2x, result "for".

Comment: Your code and your modified code does not meet the requirements, **because** you Split() and remove the parentheses ! A recursive parser needs to have the delimiters, because its if-statement will depend on it. The parser will call itself on the next character on "(" and return action on ")". Now I nearly spelled it out for you.. Success !

Comment: Done ! ```Stack myStack = new Stack();
        string sentence = "(skeeg(for)skeeg)";
        string aux = sentence;
        int begin = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++) {
            if (sentence[i] == '(')
                myStack.Push(i);
            else if (sentence[i] == ')') {
                begin = (int) myStack.Pop();
                aux = ReverseString(aux, begin, i-begin);
            }
        }
        aux = aux.Replace(@"(", "");
        aux = aux.Replace(@")", "");```